# setRateLimitPerUser does not exist

Tags: typescript, discord.js

I'm creating a slow mode command for my discord bot. I create the bot with typescript and I wonder why setRateLimitPerUser does not exist. What can I use instead of using setRateLimitPerUser to make this work?

```js
    callback: async ({
    args,
    member: staff,
    guild,
    client,
    message,
    interaction,
  }) => {
    
    const { channel } = message;

    let duration = args.toString().toLowerCase();

    if (isNaN(duration as any)) {
      return "Please provide a number of seconds";
      return;
    }

    channel.setRateLimitPerUser(duration)
  },
```

Answer (score 0):

Try turning the duration to an int in `channel.setRateLimitPerUser(duration)`
either by doing

- `channel.setRateLimitPerUser(+duration)` or
- `channel.setRateLimitPerUser(parseInt(duration))`

Comment: Thanks for the answer! 

I tried to do as you said but I still get the same problem. 

Remember I use typescript. No other ideas? It is appreciated that you help: D

Comment: Maybe it's a problem with the ```channel``` variable? I'm unsure if this would help because I feel like this is exactly what that variable is already doing doing but try ```const channel = message.guild.channels.cache.get(message.channel.id);```